Job manual release and chains
I have a job that is supposed to download a file. The file is then to be processed in another job in a chain. Now it may be that the download fails temporarily because the server is not available. In this case, I would like to try again later. So I use $this->release(600), but this marks the job as successful and continues processing the chain, which then fails in the second step.
If I use $this->fail() for the download instead, the $tries are ignored.
Is there any way to ensure that the chain is not processed further with $this->release(), or is my only option to abort the ProcessDownload job if the file has not been downloaded?
$this->release(600);

Bus::chain([
   new DownloadJob(),
   new ProcessDownloadJob()
])->dispatch();


If you require to  do this using chained jobs. you can listen on catch and then retry or do anything necessary. In this example I use a custom exception in order to know how many times the chain is failed.
in your controller:
public function  dipatchChain($attemps = 1) {
        $chain = [
           new FirstJob($attemps),
           new SecondJob(),
        ];
       
        Log::error("Job chained");

        Bus::chain($chain)->catch(function ($e) {
           // Handle the exception, log it, notify, or retry the chain
           Log::error("Job failed: ". $e->getMessage());
       
           // retry
           $attemps = $e->getData()['attemps'];
           $this->dipatchChain($attemps+1);
       
        })->dispatch();
    }


You need to fail a job in a way that Laravel recognize as failed. To trigger the catch you throw an exception inside jobs:
class FirstJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct(public $myAttemps = 0) 
    {
     
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        // Simulate an error
        if (someCondition()) {
            throw new FirstJobFailed ('Something went wrong in FirstJob', ['attemps' => $this->myAttemps]);
        }

        // Job logic
    }
}

Custom Exception:
class FirstJobFailed extends Exception 
{
    private $_data = '';

    public function __construct($message, $data) 
    {
        $this->_data = $data;
        parent::__construct($message);
    }

    public function getData()
    {
        return $this->_data;
    }
}

However, instead of chain. As an alternative you can consider doing all in one job in order to use release() method easily.

Nice one, thanks! I will add something like if($attempts > 1) ...->dispatch()->delay(now()->addMinutes(10))
